# mavros in general

Tags: ros, quadcopter, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im just wondering how to do offboard control with Mavros and how to use Mavors' utility commands and plug-ins. For example, how to use Mavros to arm the quadcopter. I know it's a stupid question so any help will be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203647/mavros-in-general/) by [cty22](https://answers.ros.org/users/21701/cty22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-02-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2015-10-29**:
Hi cty22, I have similar problem about using setpoint_position to control APM. I just wondering do you works out of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Offboard => PX4 firmware, right?

For arming look at `mavsafety` script, and `mavsafety arm`.

Offboard require arming, selecting OFFBOARD mode (`mavsys mode -c OFFBOARD`) and sending setpoints via one of setpoint plugins.
Note that OFFBOARD mode have timeout, also you may ask questions at https://gitter.im/mavlink/mavros .

---

Originally posted by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) with karma: 404 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2015-02-24**:
Also look PX4 wiki, excellent example: https://pixhawk.org/dev/offboard_control/testing

**Comment by [cty22](https://answers.ros.org/users/21701/cty22/) on 2015-03-31**:
When I do mavsys mode -c OFFBOARD. I got an error says [ERROR] [1426407538.265746064]: MODE: Unknown mode: OFFBOARD   What am I doing wrong?

**Comment by [cty22](https://answers.ros.org/users/21701/cty22/) on 2015-03-31**:
I think i'm using apm firmware. That's why. Is there a off board mode or something equivalent for apm? Thanks

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2015-04-01**:
APM:Copter now have some support, but untested by mavros users.
`mavsys mode -c GUIDED`

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2015-04-01**:
Also small fix for PX4 users: firstly start sending setpoints, then require OFFBOARD.

**Comment by [cty22](https://answers.ros.org/users/21701/cty22/) on 2015-04-08**:
I'm running into the topics not being published issue. I saw a similar question and you suggested enable mavconn to debug it. I'm not sure how to enable it. what command do you use? Thanks

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2015-04-09**:\

1. you can setup `ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE` (read ros wiki)
2. or you can do `rosservice call /mavros/set_logger_level ros.rosconsole_bridge.mavconn debug` (same may be done by `rqt`)